# FPS using mouse to move rather than keys

Tags: unity

Hi I am developing a First person game but would like to use the mouse to move on a click to move as opposed to the keys. I also need to disable Y movement and restrict the x movement to 180. What ever values I enter into the input manager, it seems to be ignoring them as I still have both x and y when I run the game.

I dabbled with the standard unity FPS but is seems very jagged on movement and from what I can see being a new user, their doesn't seem to be a way to restrict y movement. Can someone help with this or suggest a good tutorial on this type of movement. Thanks

Comment: You can lock y-axis movement in the editor in you're using a Rigidbody. If you're using a Character Controller then you can simply add a script to it that will take the y-axis position at start and then apply it in every update, so it can't move up-down.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: 
*transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));*

Or if you want to use physics: *rigidbody.AddForce(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));*

Answer (score 0):

Go to the code and find the input.Axis function and add two if statements. ~If greater than 180 =180. And the same for 0. I would recommend using global variables for the limits so you can change them in the future in the editor.